# Modify mask height dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, height, mask

I have to increase the height of .x-mask class through javascript(extjs). I will get dynamic height by using

```
var hgt = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```

Then I have to apply it instead of

```
.x-mask {
   height: 100% !important;
}
```

through javascript dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used ,

```
document.documentElement.style.height = '100%!important';
```

or

```
document.documentElement.style.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

Comment: Probably, `document.documentElement.style.height = hgt;` P.S. and the thing is to change specific css class attribute value

Comment: The div has dynamic Id. So id will not be available. Any way to change css class through js?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any element like div or span where you have assign this class like

```
<div id="mydiv" class="x-mask">
```

try this js

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.height=hgt;
```

And if you are using jQuery, then try

```
$('.x-mask').height(hgt);
```

Comment: The div has dynamic Id. So id will not be available. Any way to change css class through js?